# Ant design Form.Item validation style

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

Is it possible to add a className prop to the Form.Item validation?

```
<Form.Item name="username" rules={[
   { required: true, message: '...' },
   className="customValidation" //<- something like that, but it is not working
]}>
```

Edit:
Overriding the ant styles is not a valid solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a Issue on GitHub and and they answered with

> Form.Item supports className on it now.

https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/34110

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change style of validation messages/input border color without using className property you can use the following solution.

Following code will change the error message color and input border color from red to blue (You can add your CSS properties).

index.css

```
.ant-form-item-has-error :not(.ant-input-disabled):not(.ant-input-borderless).ant- input, 
.ant-form-item-has-error :not(.ant-input-affix-wrapper-disabled):not(.ant-input-affix-wrapper-borderless).ant-input-affix-wrapper, 
.ant-form-item-has-error :not(.ant-input-number-affix-wrapper-disabled):not(.ant-input-number-affix-wrapper-borderless).ant-input-number-affix-wrapper, 
.ant-form-item-has-error :not(.ant-input-disabled):not(.ant-input-borderless).ant-input:hover, 
.ant-form-item-has-error :not(.ant-input-affix-wrapper-disabled):not(.ant-input-affix-wrapper-borderless).ant-input-affix-wrapper:hover, 
.ant-form-item-has-error :not(.ant-input-number-affix-wrapper-disabled):not(.ant-  input-number-affix-wrapper-borderless).ant-input-number-affix-wrapper:hover {
 background-color: #fff;
 border-color: blue;
 }

.ant-form-item-explain-error {
   color: blue;
 }
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Form, Input, Button } from 'antd';

const Demo = () => {
const onFinish = (values) => {
console.log('Success:', values);
};

const onFinishFailed = (errorInfo) => {
console.log('Failed:', errorInfo);
 };

 return (
<Form
  name="basic"
  labelCol={{
    span: 8,
  }}
  wrapperCol={{
    span: 16,
  }}
  onFinish={onFinish}
  onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
>
  <Form.Item
    label="Username"
    name="username"
    rules={[
      {
        required: true,
        message: 'Please enter your username!',
      },
    ]}
  >
    <Input />
  </Form.Item>

  <Form.Item
    wrapperCol={{
      offset: 8,
      span: 16,
    }}
  >
    <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
      Submit
    </Button>
  </Form.Item>
</Form>
);
};
export default Demo;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is impossible, There is not the attribute to add the className in antd Form.Item

[image]

[image]

If you want you can use the [styled-component](https://styled-components.com/)

I add my example code for you below.

```
export const CustomItem = styled(Form.Item)`
  .ant-form-item-explain.ant-form-item-explain-error {
    color: blue;
  }
`

-------------------------------------------

<CustomItem
    name='name'
    label='Name'
    rules={[{ required: true }]}
>
    <Input
        size='large'
        autoComplete='name'
    />
</CustomItem>
```

It was working for me.

[image]